# Resolving from the middle of a promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

In my code, I'm using the Q library to chain multiple API calls like so:

```
function long_promise_chain() {
    var q = Q.defer();
    call_api_batch1()
        .then(function(v) {
            if (v.bar) {
                q.resolve();
            } else {
                return call_api_batch_2();
            }
        })
        .then(function(v) {
            if (v.bar) {
                q.resolve();
            } else {
                return call_api_batch_3();
            }
        })
        .then(function(v) {
            if (v.bar) {
                q.resolve();
            } else {
                return call_api_batch_3();
            }
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("err: " + err);
        });
    return q.promise
}
```

I am seeing that even if the chain is resolved after the first batch the next `then` block is getting run and causing an error - trying to access an undefined variable and then calling the function(err) block.

Can you please suggest the right way to resolve early.

Update:
The issue is that if the the first q.resolve() is called, I don't want the next .then in the chain to triggered. While the q.resolve is called correctly and returns control to the caller, there is an error being printed because, in the second then, there is no 'v' and the error is 'Cannot Read property bar of undefined' when testing v.bar.

Comment: *"and causing an error - trying to access an undefined variable and then calling the function(err) block"* There's no code above trying to access an undefined variable.

Comment: Making the code simple is useful, but in this case I'm afraid you've made it *too* generic. It's unclear what the subsequent `then` functions are meant to be using from the previous promise's resolution, which appears to be important here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I will try to update the question.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand you. Is this what you want?:

```
function long_promise_chain() {
    var q = Q.defer();
    var allDone = false;
    call_api_batch1()
        .then(function(v) {
            if (v.bar) {
                q.resolve();
                allDone = true;
            } else {
                return call_api_batch_2();
            }
        })
        .then(function(v) {
            if (!allDone) {
                if (v.bar) {
                    q.resolve();
                    allDone = true;
                } else {
                    return call_api_batch_3();
                }
            }
        })
        .then(function(v) {
            if (!allDone) {
                if (v.bar) {
                    q.resolve();
                    allDone = true;
                } else {
                    return call_api_batch_3();
                }
            }
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("err: " + err);
        });
    return q.promise
}
```

Comment: Well, it works and I don't have to execute the other .then blocks after resolving the first .then block. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's two separate `resolve`'s to deal with in your case.

1. First the lower case `q` which holds a deferred object.  This is the promise which you return from `long_promise_chain`.
2. Second, the promise at each stage of you chain.  Ie, the promise returned from each `then` call in the chain to the subsequent `then`.

You resolve or reject `q` by calling the method on `q` directly.  You can resolve or reject the `then` promise by *returning `Q.resolve()` or `Q.reject()`* from the `then` block.

Here's a sample:

favorite
In my code, I'm using the Q library to chain multiple API calls like so:

```
function long_promise_chain() {
    var q = Q.defer();
    call_api_batch1()
        .then(function(v) {
            if (condition) {
                q.resolve();
                return Q.reject();
            } else {
                return call_api_batch_2();
            }
        })
        .then(function(v) {
            if (condition) {
                q.resolve();
                return Q.reject();
            } else {
                return call_api_batch_3();
            }
        })
        .then(function(v) {
            if (condition) {
                q.resolve();
                return Q.reject();
            } else {
                return call_api_batch_3();
            }
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("err: " + err);
        });
    return q.promise
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I tried using return Q.resolve() after q.resolve({}) but the subsequent .then() in the chain still got executed and threw an error.

Comment: @user2738707 If you want to cancel the next stage you need to use Q.reject.  I've updated my code sample.

Comment: hey, I tried this but it is still executing the other chains after resolving!